# QGIS 3.28.3 lagging in layout

Tags: qgis, layouts, windows

I believe that I have a decent PC to run smoothly QGIS. Windows10, 16GB RAM, Nvidia Quadro P400 2GB,Intel i7 @3.80. Every time I design my map in layout and start adding tables and text boxes and images (KB size) it starts lagging. I have to disable all the guides to start working pleasantly. I am checking the task manager, and Qgis does not consume too much power in general. I don't know where is the problem. Especially when I was working Qgis with Ubuntu or Debian OS, with older versions, I never had any lagging problem. So now I am confused. Is it a Windows problem or is it a hardware problem?

Comment: Please describe very detailed, what you layout contains. E.g. expressions in text fields which grab information from map layers tend to slow down the layout very heavily.

Comment: It is a usual survey drawing. The map is simple without many layers and colours, except sometimes when I am using curved contours. The layout has an attribute table from a point vector layer with the coordinates, 2-3 text boxes with simple text, describing the laws of the area, a print screened picture from Google Earth of the area, and another simple text box with simple text of the project details. That's an average project and it lags not to much. If I insert 2-3 attritbute tables and 2-3 pictures, it's game over. It takes 2-3 seconds to begin to move a table from a point to another.

Comment: Have you experimented with the settings of the attribute tables?

Comment: In my previous message, also I add a Legend. Except the change of the width of the lines and text height in the layout no I don't change something else. Sometimes I join a vector line layer which has dimensions between points with the point layer of the coordinates I use in the layout, but I haven't noticed a correlation of this action with the lag.